# powershell: combobox only displays System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: wpf, powershell, combobox

Is there something else I need to add in order to connect the `DataTable` to the `ComboBox` or have it list the items?

Currently, it will show items, but they all are `System.Data.DataRowView` and I am not sure why.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="WPFDomainUsersBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" Height="23" Text="Domain Users"/>
...
...
...
#create a datatable to bind to our combobox
    $datatable = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
    #Define Columns
    $ColValue = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Value",([string])
    $ColText = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Text",([string])
    #add columns to datatable
    $datatable.columns.add($ColValue)
    $datatable.columns.add($ColText)

    #List option.
    $DomainUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *
    ForEach($DUsers in $DomainUsers) {
        #$WPFDomainUsersBox.Items.Add($DUsers.SamAccountName)

        $datarow = $datatable.NewRow()
        #Enter data in the row
        $datarow.Value = $DUsers.SamAccountName
        $datarow.Text = $DUsers.SamAccountName
        #Add the row to the datatable
        $datatable.Rows.Add($datarow)
    }

    $WPFDomainUsersBox.ItemsSource = $datatable.DefaultView
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `ComboBox` to the name of the column in the `DataTable` that you want to display:

```
$WPFDomainUsersBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text"
```